# Using a user selected choice from a drop-down to populate a text field in Google Forms

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, google-apps-script, textbox, google-forms

I am creating a Judging Form for a research competition and I am trying to use Google Forms to do so. What I am attempting to do is have a drop down list the Research Poster Numbers and have then have the user selected choice from the drop down fill text field for the poster title. I will be pulling the both the Poster Number and Title from an existing spreadsheet.

```js
var caseScoreForm = FormApp.openById('FormTitle');
var scoreSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadSheetName');
var lastRow = scoreSheet.getLastRow();

function fillposterNumbersDropDown(posterNumberRange) {
  var posterNumber = caseScoreForm.addListItem();
  var posterNumberValue = "";
  var posterNumberLog = "";
  var posterNumberArr = [];
  var posterNumberRange = scoreSheet.getRange('Score Sheet!A2:' + lastRow).getValues();

  //  loads the posterNumber array
  for (var i = 0; i < posterNumberRange.length; i++) {
    posterNumberValue = posterNumberRange[i][0];
    Logger.log(posterNumberValue);
    posterNumberLog = posterNumber.createChoice(posterNumberValue);
    posterNumberArr.push(posterNumberLog);
  }
  posterNumber.setTitle('Poster Number:').setChoices(posterNumberArr).setRequired(true);
}

function setPosterTitleTextResponce(posterTitleRange) {
  var posterTitleRange = scoreSheet.getRange('Score Sheet!B2:' + lastRow).getValues();
  var posterTitle = caseScoreForm.addTextItem();
  var posterTitleValue = "";
  var posterTitleLog = "";
  var posterTitleArr = [];
  var posterNumberIndex = null;
  var posterNumberChoices = FormApp.getActiveForm().getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST)[1].asListItem().getChoices();
  var userChoice = getUserChoice();

  //get the users choice index from the posterNumber dropdown
  if (userChoice != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < posterNumberChoices.length; i++) {
      if (userChoice == posterNumberChoices[i]) { // need getUserChoice();
        posterNumberIndex = i;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  //loads the posterTitle array
  for (var i = 0; i < posterTitleRange.length; i++) {
    posterTitleValue = posterTitleRange[i][0];
    posterTitleLog = Logger.log(posterTitleValue);
    posterTitleArr.push(posterTitleLog);
  }

  //print out the posterTitle using the posteNumbers index
  posterTitle.setTitle('Poster Title:').setRequired(true); // need way to wright to textfield
}
```

I think all I have left to do is just get the users choice for the active form and print it to the poster Title text field. I know there is the Get pre-filled URL link in Google forms, but we are projecting about 200 entrees for this competition.

If any one has any help/tip/suggestions or have any alternatives, please let me know.